# Username and Password not accepted error when using Google smtp server even when using app password

Tags: spring, email, smtp, boot

I'm trying to configure my Spring Boot app to send notifications using the Google SMTP server. I've generated an App Password for my app, but I keep using the same error when trying to send a message from within my app. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the application yaml (I replaced actual username and password with placeholders:

```
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: <username>
    password: <app-password>
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
        debug: true
```

Here's the console output:

```
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z21-20020a19f715000000b004eb44dae858sm1433785lfe.52 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
EHLO Igor-PC
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [37.145.40.200]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO Igor-PC
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [37.145.40.200]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=<username>, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
30959 [http-nio-9000-exec-1] WARN  o.a.a.s.u.RestorePasswordServiceImpl - Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z21-20020a19f715000000b004eb44dae858sm1433785lfe.52 - gsmtp
```

I tried setting up the app password a few times, but all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I've just sorted this out! THe thing is that my username is actually another mail service, and even though I use it as a login in my google account, it didn't work due to this fact.